# Sending sqlite data as an email attachment

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an app which gathers user data, and displays them into a listview. I also have an EmailSender class with the following function;

```
 protected void sendEmail() {
  Log.i("Send email", "");

  String[] TO = {"amrood.admin@gmail.com"};
  String[] CC = {"mcmohd@gmail.com"};
  Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
  emailIntent.setType("text/plain");


  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your subject");
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message goes here");

  try {
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
     finish();
     Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");
  } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
     "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

I want to automatically add the sqlite data into the email as an attachment. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the sqllite path as an extra like this

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(sqllitePath));
```

sqlitePath should be built like

```
sqlitePath = "file://" + sqliteFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + sqliteDbName;
```